# Unable to find the type or namespace name after moving files

Tags: c#, .net

I get this error message in Visual Studio when I'm trying to run the C# code:

> The type or namespace name 'Shape' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Is this because I changed the location of some files in the Solution Explorer? From the beginning I had the files in a folder and then I moved them outside and erased the folder. I have tried to use rebuild solution and clean, but I still get this error.

Now I have all files in the same "level" in the Solution Explorer. What can I do to get it to work again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things to try:

1. Make sure the class file containing the `Shape` class is marked as "Include in project" in the Solution Explorer.
2. In the file with the error, make sure you have an appropriate `using` statement referencing the namespace where the `Shape` class is located.
3. If the `Shape` class is in an external DLL, make sure it is referenced in your project.
4. Double-check what the namespace is for the class file that contains the `Shape` class. Depending on how you moved those files around, it may have changed and you will need to update the `using` statement where you use it.

Comment: It was different namespace in the files, so your option number 2, removed the error! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by many things. e.g. public, assembly referencing, and in a project or a solution folder. JohnFx has already handled some of these in his reply. But to get you "going" do the following:

Move all of the files into the same project within the solution. So you solution has a project and all of the files are in that one project.

This should at least get you going. Then experiment.

Good luck.